# SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0 using sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, json, session-storage

So what i'm doing is sending a form action to an iframe, and storing the form input data using JSON.stringify() just in case the form fails. Below is the code the iframe is using for the confirmation page, and the data of first console.log(). It seems to be failing at the JSON.parse section.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/common/js/jquery-1.12.0-min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    console.log(sessionStorage);
    var formdata    = sessionStorage.getItem('formdata'),
        formid      = sessionStorage.getItem('formid'),
        dataParsed  = JSON.parse(formdata);//,
        //parent      = window.parent.document;

    // We need to check if error, and if failed, then change wizard to be correct
    console.log(formdata, formid);
});
</script>
```

The console output for the javascript is below. The first console.log outputs with the sessionStorage object and below is the error of the JSON.parse method. I'm confused as to why it's not working correctly or what might be causing the issue.

```
Storage.formdata: "merchant_defined_data1=0&merchant_defined_data2=0&merchant_defined_data3=1&merchant_defined_data4=0&merchant_defined_data5=monthly&merchant_defined_data6=0.00&merchant_defined_data7=0&bill_to_forename=John&bill_to_surname=Madrigal&bill_to_address_line1=+652+S+Walnut&bill_to_address_line2=+&bill_to_address_city=Cookeville&bill_to_address_state=TN&bill_to_address_country=US&bill_to_address_postal_code=38501&bill_to_email=jmadrigal%40tappublishing.com&amount=6.00&override_custom_receipt_page=http%3A%2F%2F74.43.119.28%2Fservice%2Faccount%2Fcsresponse&override_custom_cancel_page=http%3A%2F%2F74.43.119.28%2Fservice%2Faccount%2Fcsresponse
Storage.formid: "optionalPackagesForm"
length: 2


VM8596:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (csresponse:27)
at i (jquery-1.12.0-min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.0-min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.0-min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.12.0-min.js:2)
```

UPDATE: Below shows how the object gets stored:

```
// Store the form data, and any other session data needed for failed transaction_id

var sigSelect = function(){
            var sigFields   = ['card_type','card_number','card_cvn','card_expiry_date','profile_id',
                            'locale','signed_date_time','reference_number', 'method',
                            'currency','signed_field_names','access_key','transaction_uuid',
                            'payment_method','signature','unsigned_field_names','transaction_type'],
                selectState = ':input:not(';

            $.each(sigFields, function(index, val){ selectState += '[name="'+ val +'"],'; });
            selectState = selectState.replace(/,\s*$/,"");
            return selectState += ')'
        },
inp     = $(sigSelect(), form).serialize();


sessionStorage.setItem('formdata', inp);
sessionStorage.setItem('formid', form.attr('id'));
```

Comment: it looks more like a querystring than a json object what you got there :)

Comment: To store formdata, I'm using for example JSON.stringify($('form :input')) and storing that in the formdata value.

Comment: `Storage.formdata: "merchant_defined_d... " ` is not in JSON. Why do you want to parse it ?

Comment: Can you show us how you call `sessionStorage.setItem`?

Comment: How would I create a JSON string then? Above is an edit on how I'm creating. Modifying it to have the way i'm storing that object.

Comment: Gotta agree with @Icepickle - what you have for `Storage.formdata` is a querystring, not an object, and `Storage.formid` is just a string, and neither of them look like they've been run through `JSON.parse`...

Comment: From your update you are only "proving" that you are not using JSON.stringify so why say that you did, and why try to parse it like json? Serialize will give you exactly that what you have now in your formdata, a querystring that can be send with a get request...

Answer (score 3):

```
var formData = "merchant_defined_data1=0&merchant_defined_data2=0&merchant_defined_data3=1&merchant_defined_data4=0&merchant_defined_data5=monthly&merchant_defined_data6=0.00&merchant_defined_data7=0&bill_to_forename=John&bill_to_surname=Madrigal&bill_to_address_line1=+652+S+Walnut&bill_to_address_line2=+&bill_to_address_city=Cookeville&bill_to_address_state=TN&bill_to_address_country=US&bill_to_address_postal_code=38501&bill_to_email=jmadrigal%40tappublishing.com&amount=6.00&override_custom_receipt_page=http%3A%2F%2F74.43.119.28%2Fservice%2Faccount%2Fcsresponse&override_custom_cancel_page=http%3A%2F%2F74.43.119.28%2Fservice%2Faccount%2Fcsresponse";
var dataJson = {};
(formData .split('&')).forEach(function(data){
  dataJson[data.split("=")[0]] = data.split("=")[1]; 
});

console.log(dataJson);
```

`dataJson` will contain your data in JSON Format.